# Dist-Upgrade - LibreOffice dependencies later than required

Tags: 12.04, apt, libreoffice, dependencies

When I try to update my Ubuntu box, I get this error :

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-base:
 libreoffice-base depends on libreoffice-base-core (= 1:4.2.4~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise3); however:
  Version of libreoffice-base-core on system is 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1.
 libreoffice-base depends on libreoffice-base-drivers (= 1:4.2.4~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise3); however:
  Version of libreoffice-base-drivers on system is 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1.
 libreoffice-base depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.4~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise3); however:
  Version of libreoffice-core on system is 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1.
 libreoffice-core (1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1) breaks libreoffice-base (<< 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1) and is installed.
  Version of libreoffice-base to be configured is 1:4.2.4~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise3.
 libreoffice-base-drivers (1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1) breaks libreoffice-base (<< 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~) and is installed.
  Version of libreoffice-base to be configured is 1:4.2.4~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise3.
```

For a reason I don't know, the dependencies are newer than required. I already tried install -f without success. Is there any way to repair this without doing a full reinstall of LibreOffice?

Comment: Can you post this error in English, change you system language run your command again and post the error.

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall libreoffice

Comment: I change the language of the error. Also, I already tried --reinstall without success.

Comment: Good for you, you can answer and accept your own question, if you wish to earn some rep

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I managed to resolve my situation. Mark Kirby suggested that I run this command :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
```

...but i was still getting error about unmet dependencies.

BUT! I found out that if I "override" the joker and write down every libreoffice packages installed on my computer, the command gives no error, like this :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-base libreoffice-writer libreoffice-calc
```

and so on. After this, I simply rerun an install and LibreOffice is back without a hitch.

Unfortunately, I didn't find a solution that isn't imply a full reinstall of LibreOffice